# Xamarin Mono 4.8 Upgrade App Won't run

Tags: xamarin.mac

I have a Xamarin.Mac application that I wrote. It has been working fine.

I just upgraded Xamarin today and it upgraded mono to 4.8.

Now when I try to run my app in the Xamarin IDE I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. File
>   name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

What causes this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing all of the projects over to the xamarin 4.5.2 instead of the mono 4.5 target.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building with msbuild or xbuild? msbuild is still experimental and has some issues around System.Runtime and netstandard libraries that are still being fix.

Posting a full build log link / application output log would also be useful. For more in depth debugging assistance the [Xamarin.Mac forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/categories/mac) are sometimes more appropriate than stack overflow, as this really isn't a question.